# How to process textures in OpenGL correctly?

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I have 2 models and each of them has textures.
How i load textures to my models:

```
QOpenGLTexture* TextureFromFile(const char *path, const std::string &directory, bool gamma)
{
    auto functions = QOpenGLContext::currentContext()->functions();
    auto extraFunctions = QOpenGLContext::currentContext()->extraFunctions();
    std::string filename = std::string(path);

    filename = directory + '\\' + filename;
    QOpenGLTexture* glTexture = new QOpenGLTexture(QOpenGLTexture::Target2D);
    glTexture->setData(QImage(filename.c_str()));/*.mirrored()*/  
    glTexture->bind();
    if(!glTexture->isBound())
    {
        std::cout << "glTexture wasn't bounded" << std::endl;
    }

    glTexture->generateMipMaps();

    return glTexture;
}
```

Then I just bind the texture when I draw the model.
So, for one model I should to load my image with:

```
glTexture->setData(QImage(filename.c_str()).mirrored())
```

The other one

```
glTexture->setData(QImage(filename.c_str()))
```

How i can standardize this process? Why for one model i should create mirrored texture but for another one not?

So, the first model with

```
glTexture->setData(QImage(filename.c_str()).mirrored())
```

[Looks correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jJb5A.png)

[But the second model looks very strange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sv8JE.png)

If I will load image data with

```
glTexture->setData(QImage(filename.c_str()))
```

[The first model looks strange](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H5xKX.png)

[The second looks correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/B2YaG.png)

So, my question is, how to normalize this? How can I realize, whether should I mirror the texture or not?

My fragment shader:

```
#version 440
out vec4 FragColor;

in vec2 TexCoords;
struct Material {
    sampler2D texture_diffuse1;
};

uniform Material material;

void main()
{    
    FragColor = texture(material.texture_diffuse1, TexCoords);
}
```

Comment: Can we see the code for model loading?

Comment: You can't. It's not your fault. The two models use different conventions -- one with Y pointing up, the other Y pointing down.

Comment: @YakovGalka but how can I handle it? For example, I want just to check whether i need to mirror the texture

Comment: "how can I handle it" -- open one of the models in your favorite 3d modeling program and flip the UV map.